# Forecast accuracy in different climate types

Tags: climate, weather-forecasting, predictability

Which climate is easier to be predicted. In other words. Which climate forecast results better accuracy? 
Is there any climate more convenient to be predicted? Is there any paper concerning this topic?

Comment: Depending on the method, my ansatz is that the tropics are more predictable, since persistence is a generally good indicator for daily weather. Nonetheless, I think it is important to specify what quantity.

Comment: I am mostly interested on wind forecast accuracy over different climate types. Mostly meditteranean, continental and oceanic

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus tropics more predictable ? Sorry I really disagree with that. I think mid latitudes are more predictable. Linear theory fails in the tropics. If you do not believe me read the papers of Kerry Emanuel from MIT.

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/35c1/f0ae1358b8cbc647e0c23354eeae82788d0c.pdf

Comment: @gansub I think that highlights the difference between accuracy and model uncertainty. Of course the tropics have a lot of uncertainty with regards to processes, force balances, etc. While it is not an academic article, I found this to be a supporter of my ansatz: https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/which-city-has-the-most-unpredictable-weather/. Note where the most and least predictable weather is for the U.S.